# Why does Google Calendar suggest a lot of people were born on Jan 1st?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

Google Calendar suggests that 42 of my friends have their birthdays on January 1st. Is it an error about how Google collects birthday information? There is just no way that so many people are born on that day. (Below is an image of the birthdays shown in month mode by Google Calendar, with names hidden for privacy reasons)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a built-in feature of Calendar, it doesn't assume people's birthdays are on the 1st - if a birthday is missing, it's not displayed. This seems like a 3rd party app added birthdate data and guessed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe the Jan 1st is the default date for facebook users whose information was pulled into my Google Calendar.